# Ruby on Rails - FCKEditor Absolute Image Path Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fckeditor

I am using the FCKEditor wysiwyg editor, and was wondering if anyone figured out how to use the absolute path instead of relative path after you add an image in the editor?
And if so, how.

Answer (score 1):

Search for this code in `fckeditor\editor\filemanager\browser\default\connectors\php\basexml.php`:

```
echo '<CurrentFolder path="' . ConvertToXmlAttribute( $currentFolder ) . '" url="' . ConvertToXmlAttribute( GetUrlFromPath( $resourceType, $currentFolder ) ) . '" />' ;
```

Replace it with this:

```
echo '<CurrentFolder path="' . ConvertToXmlAttribute( $currentFolder ) . '" url="'.'http://www.YOURDOMAINHERE.com' .ConvertToXmlAttribute( GetUrlFromPath( $resourceType, $currentFolder ) ) . '" />' ;
```